# What is sygnal in numpy.fft.fft

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to ask you about what is mean of what we pass "sygnal" into numpy-fft-fft.I faund important word sygnal in PyShell docstring.
It is

```
signal=[1 2 3 4 3 2](as np.array)
```

When I pass it into np.fft.fft I get

```
out np-fft-fft[15.+0.j -4.+0.j  0.+0.j -1.+0.j  0.+0.j -4.+0.j]
```

I cant understand what items in variable sygnal?
Is it

```
1)sygnal=[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6]
```

It means x coordinates of the graphic.Or it is

```
2)sygnal=[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]
```

or

```
3)sygnal=[y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6]
```

It means y coordinates of the graphic with delta=1 on OX axix?

Answer (score 1):

[Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal) is a general term for any varying quality, notably sound, light, or scientific measurements.

The amplitude measurements of a microphone sampled every fraction of a second form a one-dimensional signal of sound magnitude over time.

The intensities of light in an image form a two-dimensional signal of light intensity over space. (If the image is represented in separate colors, such as red, green, blue, it can be considered as three separate signals, one for each color, or one compound signal.)

The prices of a stock recorded over time are a signal. Measurements of a radio signal intensity over time are a signal. Position of a moving machine part over time is a signal.

Signals are often measured as intensities over time using a sensor (for sound, radio, light, position, or other properties) that reports a magnitude, and the sensor is sampled at intervals of time. In a photographic image, the intensities of light are captured using a two-dimensional array of sensors, so the signal captures a single moment in time, but we see how it varies as you move along the image from left to right in a row or from top to bottom in a column.

The FFT transforms a signal from a list of intensities over time or intensities over space to a list of intensities and phases of frequencies. As an example, consider a set of church bells each with a different resonant frequency. Given a signal taken from a microphone near a church, that signal tells you the magnitude of the sound (effectively, how hard the air is pushing against the microphone at each moment). The FFT of that signal tells you how hard each bell is ringing and its phase (where in time it started its pattern of back-and-forth vibration). The FFT output is also consider a signal, presented as frequency information instead of magnitude-in-time information.